Vivado error /usr/bin/gcc not found despite it being installed
Hi I'm trying to run a simulation in Vivado (Ubuntu 24.04) but it's telling me gcc can't be found (error XSIM 43-3388). I have confirmed that gcc is installed and that usr/bin/ is in my Path. What am I missing? Is there a setting somewhere within Vivado I need to change that I can't find?
Thanks in advance :)
